# Logic/probability riddle

Tags: logic, puzzle

The Island of Zombies: On a certain island, some of the residents have been turned into zombies, but they act just like normal people except that they only lie. The humans on the island only tell the truth. This sounds like a knight-knave situation, but the reality is more complicated: the islanders understand English, but they can only speak in their native tongue which has not yet been translated. When you ask them a yes or no question, they respond with “Gha” or “Jal.” One means yes, and the other no, but you don’t know which. You arrive on the island and are immediately captured. The leader of the Island points to a card written in English above his head. It says: “You may ask the leader any one question. If he answers “Gha” then you may visit the island peacefully, if he answers “Jal” then you will be transformed into a zombie and forced to live out your days on the island. What do you ask the leader, given that you don’t know whether he is a human or a zombie and given that you would prefer not to be a zombie? Explain your answer.

I started by thinking of asking, "is the meaning of 'gha' no?" In this case, the zombies would say "gha" which is good, but the humans would say "jal" which is what we don't want.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: A useful way to think about this is since you ask only one question, you only get one bit of information.  Here it is the answer to the question, so you must make sure you don't learn anything else.  You cannot learn whether Gha means yes, nor whether any individual is human or zombie.

Comment: @MJD your deleted answer works.  why did you delete it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  I deleted the "probability" tag and added the "puzzle" tag.

Answer (score 1):

A standard **template** to deal with knights and knaves, is to ask this:

> What would you say if I ask you [question]?

A knave would have to lie twice and therefore tell the truth -- i.e. he would lie about the [question] if you had asked him directly, so since you asked indirectly he would have to lie about the fact he would lie about [question].  This gets rid of all knight/knave issues.

(In a sense, it is sad such a  template exists, coz now most knight/knave puzzles are not fun any more.)

It only remains what [question] should be.  In the classic escape example, [question] would be "Is this the door to escape?"  In your example, the [question]  would be "Does Gha mean Yes?"  The best thing about the template is that, since we got rid of the knight/knave issue, all you need to check is that a knight will answer Gha in both cases.

Credit: IIRC I read about the template from one of the logic puzzle books by Raymond Smullyan.

Answer (score 0):

Are you human and 'Gha' means yes, or are you a zombie and 'Gha' means no?

We want our captor to say 'Gha'. If 'Gha' means yes and our captor is human, we want the answer to our question to be yes. If 'Gha' means no and our captor is human, we want the answer to be no. If 'Gha' means yes and our captor is a zombie, we want the answer to be no, because then the zombie will lie and say 'Gha', which means yes. If 'Gha' means no and our captor is a zombie, we want the answer to be yes, because the zombie will lie and say 'Gha.' The question "Are you human and 'Gha' means yes, or are you a zombie and 'Gha' means no?" will have the desired answer in each situation.

Answer (score 0):

Would you have said Gha or Jal if I became like you?

- The human can only answer *Gha* because he tells the truth.
- The zombie can not answer answer *Jal* because he lies.

Comment: Right idea but you forgot to actually make it a Yes/No question...  :)

Comment: Edited. (@antkam By the way, even if it's not a yes/no question, so long as the Zombie can't answer Jal, the first safety requirement is fulfilled. Of course, you could turn into a Zombie by some other means on the island.)

Comment: If you became like the leader, why would you say anything at all?  This still isn't a Yes/No question.  E.g. suppose the leader is human.  If you become like the leader, i.e. human, why would you say Gha or Jal or anything at all?  You haven't been asked a Yes/No question.

Comment: @antkam Edited again, thank you.